# SKView did not resume after pause

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene, skview

I am developing an application in which i have used SKView as view for View Controller.

I paused the view when user tap any button on screen and push the new UIViewController:

**Pause View Code**

`self.emitterView.paused = true;`

```
func settingButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    self.emitterView.paused = true;
    let viewCtrl = EDUIUtility.loadViewControllerFromStoryboard(EDConstant.StoryboardFileName, viewCtrlStoryboardId: EDConstant.SettingViewCtrlID)
    self.pushViewController(viewCtrl)
}
```

On viewWillAppear i just resume the view by following code:

**resume View Code**

`self.emitterView.paused = false;`

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.emitterView.paused = false;
}
```

But it is not working view is still paused until i tapped on a screen.
I also checked the update method of scene presented by emitter view and working.

**Note: Same Code is working fine on application background and foreground.**

View Controller Push and Pop

```
func pushViewController(viewController:UIViewController){
    UIView.transitionWithView(self.navigationController!.view, duration: 0.50,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
            self.navigationController!.pushViewController(viewController, animated: false)
        }, completion: nil)
}

func popViewController(){
    UIView.transitionWithView(self.navigationController!.view, duration: 0.50,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {
            self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(false)
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: From what I am guessing,  self.emitterView may not be the same object from when you pause to when you resume,  could you post some more code and clarify a little bit about what is going on

Comment: The other thing that may be happening if I interpret this a different way, is you pause the game, a new view controller pops ups, you close the new view controller, and expect the game to unpause at that moment.  If this is the case, how are you presenting the new view controller, and how are you returning?  viewWillAppear may not be called in some circumstances.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon  Thanks for the reply. 1) Self.emitterView is IBOutlet. 2)I checked that view will appear is called. It is just push and pop of navigation controller.

Comment: That means nothing in regards to your problem,  just that it is the variable that is associated with the view,  ok if it is called,  then we need to investigate further,  paste the entire function that .paused is being used in.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon  sorry i did not get that. If you are asking for Emitter view then it is an IBOutlet and class of emitter view is SKView in storyboard.

Comment: I am asking for the entire viewwillappear code, and the class that it is in, and the function that pauses,  with the class that is in

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95474/discussion-between-saurav-nagpal-and-knight0fdragon).